# Probability desiderata: Why is AB|E not a function just of A|E and B|E?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, logic

So I've been reading Jaynes(2003) and Tribus (1969). In their exposition of the reasoning for the plausibility of events they say that the plausibility of $ AB|E$ is **not** a function of $ A|E$ and $B|E$. Only Tribus offers a mathematically worked out argument as to why. He does so in this section of the book: [Take a look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYn8M.png).

Some context as to what each symbol means:

- $A, B, E$ are all letters representing a statement.
- $b$ is the negation of $B$
- Two statements written together will be taken to mean both statements
  are true. (Conjunction).
- $u, y, i, v, x$ are all real numbers.
- $u = [AB|E], y = [B|AE], v = [A|E], x = [B|E]$
- $i$ represents that a statement is impossible
- $F_2(v, x)$ is just a function of $v$ and $x$

What I find confusing here is that the demonstration begins y saying that $A$ is equal to NOT $B$ but later on $A$ and $B$ are said to be independent, which is contradictory since determining the value of $A$ will determine the value of $B$ and vice-versa. Hence I don't see why $[AB|E']=i$ if $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Thank all of you for your help!

P.S.: We are not talking about probabilities just yet only what the authors call "credibilities" this will eventually evolve in to probability theory but in this context it does not apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about it for a while I think this is a more clear reasoning as to why this function is inappropriate. I am not 100% confident this is the correct explanation so if anyone has any comments that would help improve this explanation please post them below. Anyway here it is:

- if $E = ``A = b"$ then $F_2 = i, \forall i$
- Take $E' = ``A \: and \: B \: are \: independent"$ (also for clarity denote $A'$ and $B'$ as statements given $E'$)
- For some combination of $A, A', B, B', E, E'$ make it so that at least in one case $[A|E]=[A'|E']=v' \land [B|E]=[B'|E']=x'$
- Input these values in $F_2$
- Since $F_2 ([A|E], [B|E]) = i = F_2 (v', x')$
- Using $F_2$ under $E'$ we get:
- $i = F_2 (v', x') = F_2 ([A'|E'], [B'|E'])$ which makes no sense, since $A'$ and $B'$ are independent and so the credibility that they both happen must **not** be impossible. This would mean $i=F_2 ([A'|E'], [B'|E'])\neq i$ which is a contradiction.

One last comment, this shows that $F_2$ is an inadequate function to calculate the plausibility of $AB|E$. However, there is no proof to my knowledge, that shows that there must be a function by which the plausibility of $AB|E$ can be calculated. Hence, I find this proof by contradiction somewhat flawed as it is not clear that there must be an alternative way of calculating the plausibility of $AB|E$. Once again if anyone knows how to solve this problem your comments are highly welcomed.

I leave this here in hopes someone finds it useful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If $E$ is a tautology, $A, \,B$ are counterexamples iff they're dependent. More generally, $A, \,B$ are counterexamples iff they're [dependent conditionally on $E$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_dependence).

Comment: thanks for your answer, however I don't see how this solves the problem, why then is $ AB|E $ not a function of $ A|E $ and $ B|E $?

Comment: Also I don't believe being counter examples is a necessary condition for dependency. I could be wrong if so, please provide an explanation.

Comment: @cachdies I meant counterexamples to $P(AB|E)=P(A|E)P(B|E)$. If $E$ is a tautology, in general $P(AB|E)=P(AB)=P(A)P(B|A)=P(A|E)P(B|AE)$, but $P(B|A)$ can differ from $P(B)$; for arbitrary $E$, $P(AB|E)=P(A|E)P(B|AE)$, but $P(B|AE)$ can differ from $P(B|E)$.

Comment: but $E="A=b"$ meaning $E$ is not true for all cases of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: $AB|E$ is not a function of $A|E$ and $B|E$ if for some arrangement of $A, B, E$ such a function gives an absurd answer (or more formally, if it violates one of the desiderata).

Comment: @cachdies Indeed, in your example, $P(AB|E)=0$.